# Multiple Services of same image in different Stacks + Docker UCP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows, docker-ucp

I want to know if the below scenario is even possible since I tried unsuccessfully.

Have two Stacks StackA and STackB.

StackA has services ServiceA1 and ServiceA2 with published ports 8081 & 8082 respectively.
StackB has services ServiceB1 and ServiceB2 with published ports 9081 & 9082 respectively.

ServiceA1 and ServiceB1 are based on Image I1
ServiceA2 and ServiceB2 are based on Image I2

For whatever reason, both the services in StackB are not responding where as the ones in StackA work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is about Image I2 itself not docker config etc. Can you give more information about what services do your docker run commands and docker logs of containers to investigate the problem ?